# Always encrypted provisioning CNG with powershell exception

Tags: sql-server, powershell, always-encrypted, cng

I'm having a problem while making a powershell script for creation of Always Encrypted  column encryption keys

When I run these functions from the SqlServer powershell module,
I get the following error.

> ```
> # $cngProviderName "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider";
> # $cngKeyName = name of the CngKeyIdentifier
> $cmkSettings = New-SqlCngColumnMasterKeySettings -CngProviderName $cngProviderName -KeyName $cngKeyName;
>
> # This command is throwing the exception
> $encryptedValue = New-SqlColumnEncryptionKeyEncryptedValue -TargetColumnMasterKeySettings $cmkSettings
> ```

> S
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.Types.AlwaysEncryptedManager'
> threw an exception. --->
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.Management.AlwaysEncryptedManagement'
> threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method
> 'get_SerializationSettings' in type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an
> implementation.

I'm really puzzled as to why I'm getting the error, I'm not using the Azure KeyVault based functionality, and I'm not sure why I get this reflection error.

I've tried extensively looking for this error, but I couldn't find the problem.
When using the certificate based approach I get the same problem.

Is there any one who can tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into assembly dependencies and how these work in powershell, I looked at "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" and figured that it could be in conflict with existing Azure modules that I've loaded.

After removing all of the Azure modules in powershell:
(src): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-2008

> Get-Module -Name Azure* -ListAvailable | Uninstall-Module -Force
> -Verbose -ErrorAction Continue Get-Module -Name Azs.* -ListAvailable | Uninstall-Module -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Continue Get-Module
> -Name Az.* -ListAvailable | Uninstall-Module -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Continue

I managed to run my script.
In removing them I ensured there weren't any conflicts.